# npm install module from gitlab

Tags: node.js, https, npm, installation, gitlab

In node module package.json I have:

```
"repository" : {
"type":"git",
"url":"https://git.domainName.com/Mastash3ff/someprojectname.git"
},
```

Trying to install via npm.
Tried various commands like from https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install:

```
npm install gitlab:git.domainName.com/Mastash3ff/someProjectName.git
```

also tried

npm install https://git.domainName.com/Mastash3ff/someProjectName.git

https:// install command hangs after enter is pressed.  npm install gitlab command spits out:

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/Mastash3ff/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@gitlab.com:git.domainName.com/Mastash3ff%2FsomeProjectName.git /home/Mastash3ff/.npm/_git-remotes/git-gitlab-com-git-domainName-com-Mastash3ff-2FsomeProjectName-git-a88a1dff9012cf9dc7b0780cba303741: Cloning into bare repository '/home/Mastash3ff/.npm/_git-remotes/git-gitlab-com-git-domainName-com-Mastash3ff-2FsomeProjectName-git-a88a1dff9012cf9dc7b0780cba303741'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/Mastash3ff/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@gitlab.com:git.domainName.com/Mastash3ff%2FsomeProjectName.git /home/Mastash3ff/.npm/_git-remotes/git-gitlab-com-git-domainName-com-Mastash3ff-2FsomeProjectName-git-a88a1dff9012cf9dc7b0780cba303741: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/Mastash3ff/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@gitlab.com:git.domainName.com/Mastash3ff%2FsomeProjectName.git /home/Mastash3ff/.npm/_git-remotes/git-gitlab-com-git-domainName-com-Mastash3ff-2FsomeProjectName-git-a88a1dff9012cf9dc7b0780cba303741: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
.....
```

For gitlab, we don't have ssh auth setup so we only use https://.  Not sure why it would be asking for public key.  The way we git clone is by pointing it to cert file.  I also have my ~/.npmrc file pointing to:

```
  cafile=/home/Mastash3ff/git.someDomainName.com.cert
```

I'm out of ideas. I'm hoping this problem can be solved my pointing out incorrect npm install command usage :/

Answer (score 0):

Check your access to the repo.

> Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: Not that easy.  I can git clone just fine from it.  Also have private key added to ssh-agent.